# Using memcmp Vs. == in c (embedded) and unexpected errors

Tags: c, syntax, embedded

I keep hearing that using `==` operator to compare chars can cause some problems.

My question is - what kind of problems?

For example, is there any difference between using:

```
if (Text[0] == 'A') { ; }
```

and

```
if (!memcmp(Text, "A", 1)) { ; }
```

Comment: No, there should not be any difference. Your question is quite vague, where are you hearing these things from?

Comment: This is not really related to embedded systems, they work the same as any C platform in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've blurred together two separate ideas.

There's nothing wrong with

```
if (Text[0] == 'A')
```

It'll do just what you want.

What you probably heard, and what you can't do, is

```
if (Text == "A")
```

That will virtually always come out false, even if `Text` contains "A".

If you want to compare strings, you generally use `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(Text, "A") == 0)
```

Of course this only works on properly-formed, null-terminated strings.

Finally, while you can certainly do

```
if (!memcmp(Text, "A", 1))
```

if you really want to, it's a strange and potentially inefficient usage, which doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot Steve.